# NPOI Word creating numbered list

Tags: c#, .net, npoi

As `NPOI` is not that great with documentation, I am posting this question. Is it possible to create numbered list using `NPOI` library for `.NET`?

1. test 1
2. test 2
3. and so on....

There is an [example](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi/tree/master/examples/xwpf/CreateBullet) for creating bullet point list. However could not find example which would use numbers,but not bullet point

Comment: I think you do need to look at OOXML documentation too when using POI and NPOI, yes. This is probably the relevant bit: http://officeopenxml.com/WPnumbering.php You should be able to set properties on the XWPFNumbering or abstract numbering in the example you've found. But I don't know the specifics myself sorry, so can't post an answer.

Comment: This question doesn't contain any code, and the link has gone stale.  The answer may have been useful at one point, but without reference code, this question has become useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that example you have provided 
just remove this line

> string abstractNumId = numbering.AddAbstractNum();

**(line 18)**
and set

> string numId = numbering.AddNum("1");

and it should work as you need